# How to create rank column based on multiple columns with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c', 'd'],
                    'buy': [datetime.date(2020,4,10), datetime.date(2020,4,10), datetime.date(2020,5,21), 
                              datetime.date(2020,8,28), datetime.date(2020,8,28), datetime.date(2021,2,25), 
                              datetime.date(2021,12,1), datetime.date(2021,12,1), datetime.date(2021,12,17)],
                    'use': [None, None, None, 
                              datetime.date(2020,8,30), None, datetime.date(2021,3,4), 
                              datetime.date(2020,7,8), datetime.date(2021,12,20), None]})
```

I would like to create a `rank` column, which will be grouped by `id` and will be ascending first by `buy` and then by `use`. If the `use` is `None` and the `buy` is the same, then the same `rank` should be given.

I tried:

```
foo['buy'] = pd.to_datetime(foo['buy'])
foo["rank"] = foo.groupby("id")[["buy", "use"]].rank(method="dense", ascending=True)
```

The above code works as expected for all `id`s **except** `id=c`

Any ideas why ?

**UPDATE**

The expected output should be:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c', 'd'],
                    'buy': [datetime.date(2020,4,10), datetime.date(2020,4,10), datetime.date(2020,5,21), 
                              datetime.date(2020,8,28), datetime.date(2020,8,28), datetime.date(2021,2,25), 
                              datetime.date(2021,12,1), datetime.date(2021,12,1), datetime.date(2021,12,17)],
                    'use': [None, None, None, 
                              datetime.date(2020,8,30), None, datetime.date(2021,3,4), 
                              datetime.date(2020,7,8), datetime.date(2021,12,20), None], 
'rank': [1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1]})
```

Comment: what would happen if you had an extra row with `b 2020-08-28  2020-08-29`?

Comment: @mozway then the `rank` column should be: `[1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1]`, assuming that the row you mention would be at index 3

Comment: so a None makes other non None values have the same rank?

Comment: @mozway the same `rank` with the rows that have the same `id` **and** `buy`, to be more explicit :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your comments, within an id/buy group, any None makes the values have the same rank.

Thus, a first step is to mask all use values if there is any None within this group. Then, to rank on several columns you need to aggregate as tuple:

```
foo['rank'] = (foo
 .assign(use2=foo.groupby(['id', 'buy'])['use']
                 .transform(lambda s: '' if s.isna().any() else s)
         )
 [['buy', 'use2']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
 .groupby(foo['id']).rank(method='dense', na_option='top')
)
```

output:

```
  id        buy         use  rank
0  a 2020-04-10        None     1
1  a 2020-04-10        None     1
2  a 2020-05-21        None     2
3  b 2020-08-28  2020-08-30     1
4  b 2020-08-28        None     1
5  b 2021-02-25  2021-03-04     2
6  c 2021-12-01  2020-07-08     1
7  c 2021-12-01  2021-12-20     2
8  d 2021-12-17        None     1
```

Comment: This throws an error to me: `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. I am using pandas version `'1.1.1'`

Comment: Can you comment the lines of the pipeline and uncomment one by one to identify where the error comes from? Are you using the provided dataset?

Comment: Yes, I am trying it at the sample dataframe provided. The full traceback error:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-295-081db3b8f10c> in <module>
     21          )
     22  [['buy', 'use2']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
---> 23  .groupby(foo['id']).rank(method='dense', na_option='top')
     24 )`

Comment: Sorry I checked again and it works fine for me. You need to comment the operations to be able to identify the step that fails

Comment: it fails here for me: `.groupby(foo['id']).rank(method='dense', na_option='top')` :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a more efficient way, but this works:

```
foo['buy'] = pd.to_datetime(foo['buy'])
foo["rank"] = foo.groupby(["id"])[["buy", "use"]].rank(method="dense", ascending=True)
foo["rank2"] = foo.groupby(["id"])[["buy", "use"]].rank(method="first", ascending=True)

foo = foo.merge(foo.groupby('id')['use'].apply(lambda x: x.isnull().any()).to_frame('BOOL').reset_index(), on='id')
foo['rank_f'] = np.where(foo['BOOL'], foo['rank'], foo['rank2'])
```

And `rank_f` is the correct column